# c# randomNumber in array == winNumber

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, random

So i'm a beginner in coding, (1month).
I have been changing the code for 4 days now, no luck.
i'm stuck at getting my randomNumber == winNum to break.
The user gets 10 numbers, if the user writes (lets say winNum is 9)
1,2,5,9,10,11.... and so on. The code wont pick the number in the array, and print the "you lucky".
The code used to work. 9.2.3.4.5..... and so on, where it gets "you lucky" but not anymore.
I also get "you lose""you lose""you lose" and "End of the game".

Unsure what i'm doing wrong.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // -int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());   // this to change amount of variables the user wants instead of [x]
        int[] numbers = new int[10];  //  task 1, modul 3. The 10 in the array is a statment for how many varibles this array can hold.
                                     // you can have as many varibles as you want.
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();
        int winNum = randomNumbers.Next(1, 26);
        Console.WriteLine(winNum);
        Console.WriteLine("Pick your 10 numbers! "); // här får vi våra 10 tal av användaren 
            for (int hallon = 0; hallon < 10; hallon++)  //this loop will print the users numbers
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine($"Your have used: {hallon}" ); // här får vi våra 10 tal av användaren 
            try
            {
                numbers[hallon] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());  // numbers lagrar våra 10 tal som kommer spelas nu mot winNum
            }
            catch (SystemException e) // going to catch if the user writes in a letter instead of a number        
            {
                --hallon;
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            if (numbers[hallon] < 1 || numbers[hallon] > 25)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Write a number within 1-25. ");
                    --hallon;
                }
            } 
        for (int hallon = 0; hallon < 10; hallon++)
        {
            if (numbers[hallon] == winNum)  // vad gör jag om jag vill ha två vinnande resultat? 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Lucky number:" + numbers[hallon]);
                break;
            } ////task 2 modul 3 this loops my array untill i have all varbiles printed 
        }

        for (int hallon = 0; hallon < 10; hallon++)
        {
            if (numbers[hallon] != winNum)
            Console.WriteLine("You lost");

        }
        Console.WriteLine("End of the game");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Learning [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is an extremely valuable skill for a programmer.
Please go through the linked page and apply the techniques described there to your problem to narrow down the cause of the error.

Comment: As vc has spotted - your indenting is off, and so lots is happening in the first "for" loop. The two } on the same line at the end is a hint of that. Try fixing the indenting (there are tools that will do this for you) and it may make things cleaner. Unlike python, the indenting in C# is just for programmer convenience, it doesn't make a difference to the compiler

Comment: I have been using the debug tool, that visual studios has, however(the program runs without any errors)" so the code isn'" technically "wrong". but it does not do what i want it to do.   but i appricaite your feedback --PranavHosangadi. 

@StuartMoore  I know that my "for loops" at the end are "wrong" or maybe not even needed as micke wrote in his explination. 
I know that indenting in other software as python theres different function, I will try and make my code cleaner, and stop using unnessary code. 
As i stated before. Thank you for taking your time!.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue you have here is that the "break" keyword only goes out of its own for loop. You have one for loop that looks to see if the winning number was in the guesses, and prints "Lucky number" if so - but then it goes through all of the guesses again and prints "You lost". So even if I guess correctly on one of my 10, I'd expect to see "Lucky Number" then 9 "You lost" lines.

One way to solve this is to have a "won" boolean variable that's set to true if you find the winning number, and only print "you lost" if its false after the "Lucky number" for loop.

A couple of extra thoughts:

- Your "Catch" statement can end up with the `hallon` variable as -1 on the             `if (numbers[hallon] < 1 || numbers[hallon] > 25)` line, which i think would cause an error. Suggest that you use `continue` within the catch block, which will mean it goes to the top of the loop again. (To try this, type a letter as your very first response)
- Rather than `numbers`, `guesses` may be a clearer name for the variable.

Comment: Didn't think of boolean's, will try some, thanks for the input!
I've noticed that i'm bad at writing the functions. my friends told me the same. 
I appraicate the feedback. and so quickly

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of iterating over every number to find your result, you should do something like this instead:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // -int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());   // this to change amount of variables the user wants instead of [x]
        int[] numbers = new int[10];  //  task 1, modul 3. The 10 in the array is a statment for how many varibles this array can hold.
                                        // you can have as many varibles as you want.
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();
        int winNum = randomNumbers.Next(1, 26);
        Console.WriteLine(winNum);
        Console.WriteLine("Pick your 10 numbers! "); // här får vi våra 10 tal av användaren 
        for (int hallon = 0; hallon < 10; hallon++)  //this loop will print the users numbers
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"Your have used: {hallon}"); // här får vi våra 10 tal av användaren 
            try
            {
                numbers[hallon] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());  // numbers lagrar våra 10 tal som kommer spelas nu mot winNum
            }
            catch (SystemException e) // going to catch if the user writes in a letter instead of a number        
            {
                --hallon;
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            if (numbers[hallon] < 1 || numbers[hallon] > 25)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Write a number within 1-25. ");
                --hallon;
            }
        }

        if (numbers.Any(n => n == winNum))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You won! The lucky number was:" + winNum);
        } else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You lost");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("End of the game");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: It works for some reason, but i don't understand the code below with 
 if (numbers.Any(n => n == winNum)) What does this function do? 
I think i understand that numbers.any (will pick the "winNum" and put it as correct.
but what happens if input user puts 5 9s(will the code not write 5 times "you won!..."?

Comment: .Any is a LINQ query that is performed on a collection such as your numbers array. The query makes use of a lambda expression which is the "n => n == winNum" part. A better name for "n" would be "number" such that numbers.Any(number => number == winNum). Any only checks whether at least one of the elements in the collection satisfies a condition and then returns a true boolean value. It is basically shorthand for looping through the collection and returning true if you find the first element that satisfies the condition and not looping further. The if statement will then be true.

Comment: @Ruan you don't understand how much i of relif you've given me, Thank you a lot Ruan for the help, and guidance, if you ever come to sweden let me buy you a meal. 
Thanks a lot.